# No se genera archivo .xcworkspace

Tags: ios, genexus

Veníamos realizando desarrollos para IOS sin inconvenientes, de hecho tenemos publicado en el APPSTORE hasta la versión 1.7.
Actualmente en Genexus 17 u6 la especificación y compilación de la kb se finaliza correctamente pero no genera el archivo .xcworkspace en la MAC necesario para poder abrir el proyecto y poder continuar con la compilación y posterior subida al APPStore.
La version de MACOS es Monterrey 12.0.1.

Observación: En otras kb que están en la misma máquina y versión lo genera correctamente.

Pruebas que se realizaron:

1. Rebuill all.
2. Bajar nuevamente la kb de gxserver.
3. Comentar todo el objeto Main y sus call.
4. Eliminar la carpeta web para que genere todo nuevamente.
5. Revisar las configuraciones en la mac.
6. Intentar compilar en la mac el objeto xcodproj.
7. Revisar la cuenta en el appstore conect.
8. Exportar e importar todos los objetos en una kb nueva.

Todas insatisfactoriamente en las cuales sigue sin generar el .xcworkspace.

Answer (score 0):

El archivo `.xcworkspace` no se genera siempre, solo se genera si es necesario(*).

Si no está ese archivo entonces el proyecto queda generado como un `.xcodeproj`. Ese sí debería estar y abrir el `.xcodeproj` te debería permitir ejecutar la aplicación sin problemas.

(*) Es necesario si se usa algún proyecto externo que se integre usando CocoaPods.